# error: no graphics toolkits are available! octave

Tags: graphics, octave, toolkit

I have installed Octave 4.2.1(CLI) on Ubuntu 16.04 using commands like ./configure,make and sudo make install. When I try to use plot() function,it throws following functions.

```
Plotting Data ...
error: no graphics toolkits are available!
error: called from
figure at line 86 column 7
plotData at line 6 column 1
ex1 at line 47 column 1
```

When I tried available_graphics_toolkit().I get following output

```
octave:17> available_graphics_toolkits()
ans = {}(1x0)
```

Comment: Do you have gnuplot installed?

Comment: As the configure script told you at the end, it hasn't found the needed libs to compile the FLTK backend and the Qt backend. And it's very likely you haven't installed gnuplot

Comment: @MichaelO. I had installed gnuplot by _sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11_ if I fire gnupot on terminal. I says gnuplot is installed Version 4.6

Comment: @Andy Can you tell how to get octave (GUI + CLI version) running on ubuntu but version should be higher than 4.0.0 as it has issues with submitting codes with Coursera's server?

Comment: @AmeyChaudhary compiling from source is easy: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Compiling_from_source Just execute the commands listed below "To install all of these on Ubuntu 16.04, type ", mkdir a build directory, run ./configure and make as you did